# @Id and @Field on same variable?

Tags: spring-data-couchbase

Is there a way to achieve `@Id` and `@Field` on the same variable of a `@Document` so the variable is also saved inside the document? I'm trying to preserve the data I'm importing as much as I can, even though I get the design practices followed by the developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @Id annotation will take priority over @Field, so no the id cannot be persisted as both document ID and value inside the document.
Quickest way to achieve that is probably to duplicate the id field as a separate @Field annotated attribute?

Comment: Thank you Simon :)

Comment: Simon is the the only way to do this?  I don't see a good reason to duplicate an attribute in my document model if it isn't required.